# Using ExceptionReceived in OnMessageOptions

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to use the method `QueueClient.OnMessage(Action<BrokeredMessage>, OnMessageOptions)`. In the `OnMessageOptions` I coded this simple `ExceptionReceived` event:

```
void LogErrors(object sender, ExceptionReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Exception != null)
  {
    Trace.TraceError("Exception captured: " + e.Exception.Message);
  }
}
```

My doubt is how to get the "LogErrors" the `BrokeredMessage` that is being processend in the callback in order to save a log with errors when BrokeredMessages are occured.

Comment: Can you just try to throw an exception to see if your method is reached ?

Comment: When I throw an exception in the callback code then the LogErrors is executed, but my trouble is how to get the message that is being processed in the callback either using the LogErrors paremeters or other way...

Comment: what do you have in the sender parameter ? You should be able to find something inside one of the paramters

Answer (score 2):

I tried to see how to get the message from/within the `ExceptionReceived` callback but the information is not present in the arguments. Here is my sample code:

```
var connectionString = "my-connection-string";
var queueName = "my-queue-name";
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

var options = new OnMessageOptions();
options.ExceptionReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Neither sender or args contains information about the message being processed
};

client.OnMessage(brokeredMessage =>
{
    throw new Exception();
}, options);
```

Depending on your need, the simple solution is to wrap your callback inside a try/catch:

```
client.OnMessage(brokeredMessage =>
{
    try
    {
        // Process the message
        ...

       // Complete the message (depends on the )
       brokeredMessage.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Trace.TraceError("Exception captured: " + ex.Message);

        // Here you have access to the brokeredMessage so you can log what you want.
        ...    
        //Abandon the message so that it could be re-process ??
        brokeredMessage.Abandon();        
    }

}, options);
```

After you can put this wrapper in a function or create an extension method for `QueueClient` :

```
public static class QueueClientExtensions
{
    public static void OnCustomMessage(this QueueClient queueClient, Action<BrokeredMessage> callback,
        OnMessageOptions onMessageOptions)
    {
        queueClient.OnMessage(message =>
        {
            try
            {
                // process the message
                callback(message);

                //complete if success
                message.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Here you have access to the brokeredMessage so you can log what you want.
                // message.GetBody<string>() 
                Trace.TraceError("Exception captured: " + ex.Message);

                //Abandon the message so that it could be re-process
                message.Abandon();
            }

        }, onMessageOptions);
    }
}
```

And call this method in the same way:

```
var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
queueClient.OnCustomMessage(brokeredMessage =>
{
    // Process the message
    ...
}, new OnMessageOptions());
```

Comment: Thanks to confirm that the BrokeredMessage not was available in ExceptionReceived callback. The simple try/catch solution it's good for me!

Comment: @AlbertAixendri, can you accept the answer if it is ok for you ?